# SQL Average Group By

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, average

I have two tables, Players and GameLog.

Players has Position and Player_ID

GameLog has Player_ID, Opponent, and Points Scored

My goal is to return the average points scored against each opponent over the last 15 days by the Position "C"

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW NBAGameLog.Opp, 
     (SELECT AVG(NBAGameLog.Points)
     FROM NBAGameLog INNER JOIN Players ON NBAGameLog.Player_ID = Players.Player_ID
     WHERE (((NBAGameLog.Date_Played) Between Date()-15 And Date())) AND Players.Position = "C") AS Expr1
FROM Players INNER JOIN NBAGameLog ON Players.Player_ID = NBAGameLog.Player_ID
GROUP BY NBAGameLog.Opp;
```

This returns a list of all the teams and the overall average points scored, as opposed to being separated by team. For example, it returns:

```
ATL 19.12
BOS 19.12
NY  19.12
```

When it should be showing the average points agains ATL, the average points against BOS, etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Haha, first the triple double question now this, you trying to predict NBA games or something?  If you end up with a good system let me know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your question:

> My goal is to return the average points scored against each opponent over the last 15 days by the Position "C"

This shouldn't require fancy footwork to answer.  It seems like a basic aggregation query.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT NBAGameLog.Opp, AVG(NBAGameLog.Points)
FROM Players INNER JOIN
     NBAGameLog
     ON Players.Player_ID = NBAGameLog.Player_ID
WHERE (NBAGameLog.Date_Played Between Date()-15 And Date() AND
      Players.Position = "C"
GROUP BY NBAGameLog.Opp;
```

Comment: Wow, I feel silly...I feel like I tried something like this and it wasn't working. So simple, thanks! Also, it won't let me accept an answer so quickly, but I'll do it asap...thanks again.